# how can i create a pdf document without saving it on the android device's storage?

Tags: android, pdf, kotlin, document

I'm interested in creating a document pdf without saving it on the device's storage, the programming language that i'm using is kotlin.

The thing is that I am not interested in the fact that once the file is created, it is stored in the phone's storage, but rather when the file has been created, a preview of the document is displayed, and I decide if I want to print it or send it by mail or by some other way, but ***do not store it on the device***.

I was looking for a way to do this but i haven't found anything on the internet, so I'll really appreciate any suggestions.

here is an example of my code:

```
private fun createDocument() {
    val proceedBtn: Button = findViewById(R.id.process_payment)
    val invoiceDocument: String = "invoice.pdf"

    try {
        val document = Document()
        //open to write

        val instance = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, FileOutputStream())
        document.open()

        //settings
        document.pageSize = PageSize.A2
        document.addCreationDate()
        document.addAuthor("John Doe")
        document.addCreator("John Doe")

        //font setting
        val colorAccent = BaseColor(0, 153, 204, 255)
        val headingFontSize = 20.0f
        val valueFontSize = 26.0f

        //custom Font
        val fontName = BaseFont.createFont("assets/fonts/NotoSerif-Regular.ttf",
            "UTF-8", BaseFont.EMBEDDED)

        //Add Title to document
        var titleStyle = Font(fontName, 36.0f, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK)
        addNewItem(document, "Order details", Element.ALIGN_CENTER, titleStyle)

        val headingStyle = Font(fontName, headingFontSize, Font.NORMAL, colorAccent)
        addNewItem(document, "Order No:", Element.ALIGN_LEFT, headingStyle)

        var valueStyle = Font(fontName, 36.0f, Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK)
        addNewItem(document, "1234567", Element.ALIGN_CENTER, valueStyle)

        addLineSeparator(document)
        addNewItem(document, "Order Date:", Element.ALIGN_LEFT, valueStyle)
        addNewItem(document, "25/09/2019", Element.ALIGN_LEFT, valueStyle)

        addLineSeparator(document)
        addNewItem(document, "Acount Name:", Element.ALIGN_LEFT, headingStyle)
        addNewItem(document, "John Doe", Element.ALIGN_LEFT, valueStyle)

        addLineSeparator(document)

        //Product detail
        addLineSpace(document)
        addNewItem(document, "Product Details", Element.ALIGN_CENTER, titleStyle)

        addLineSeparator(document)

        addNewItemWithLeftAndRight(document, "Pizza ", "(0,0%)", titleStyle, valueStyle)
        addNewItemWithLeftAndRight(document, "12.0*10000", "12000.0", titleStyle, valueStyle)

        addNewItemWithLeftAndRight(document, "Humburger ", "(0,0%)", titleStyle, valueStyle)
        addNewItemWithLeftAndRight(document, "12.0*10", "120.0", titleStyle, valueStyle)

        addLineSeparator(document)

        addLineSpace(document)
        addLineSpace(document)

        addNewItemWithLeftAndRight(document, "Total", "12120.0", titleStyle, valueStyle)

        //close
        document.close()

        Toast.makeText(this@InvoiceActivity, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

        printPDF()

    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e("error", ""+e.message)
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to indicate what errors you are getting.

Comment: I haven't any error yet because i have not tested it... i just want to know if there is a way to do this thing using iText library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this without saving the pdf

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/pdf/PdfDocument